# Translating java code to python, IDE suggestions?

Tags: java, algorithm, python-2.7

I'm currently in the process of learning python, so I tried to rewrite a project I had in java to python. I'm unsure where I went wrong. The code is trying to assign n nodes to k channels and print the resulting configurations/sets. I accept being shut down in the comments as I really can't get my head around figuring out what's wrong with my code, probably 'cause I only know Java. Is it possible that this could be because I'm using terminal rather than a standard Python IDE? 
Also, this is my first question on the StackOverflow platform so if there's any way to change my approach to asking the question I'd like to know and learn.
set_of_channels is meant to hold a generated set
available_combos keeps tracks of each generated set based on the input

Given 3 nodes and 2 channels,  this is the output
Python

```
1 sets with occupancies: []  
1 sets with occupancies: ['3'] 
Total number of assignments: 2
```

Java

```
3 Nodes, 2 Channels: 
1 set(s) with occupancies: [0, 3]  
3 set(s) with occupancies: [1, 2]  
3 set(s) with occupancies: [2, 1]  
1 set(s) with occupancies: [3, 0]  
Total number of assignments: 8
```

Unsure whether to put new code as my post may be too long, don't know if that's not stack overflow etiquette

```
def start():
availableCombos = [[]]
numberOfNodes = raw_input("How many nodes?")
numberOfChannels = raw_input("How many channels?")
index = 0
setOfChannels = [numberOfChannels]
while True:
    generate(numberOfNodes, setOfChannels,
             index, numberOfNodes, availableCombos)
    totalAssignments(availableCombos, numberOfNodes)


# The base case is the last channel
# Set the channel to have the value of nodes
# currentChannel should be set to 0
# as this is the base that lists in java work with
# it is incremented with every call so as to fill up next channel
# remaining nodes helps to keep track of nodes
# to put into channels based on nodes in previous channels
# As arrays are filled they are copied into the list of available combinations
def generate(nodes, combo, currentChannel, remainingNodes, availableCombos):
sum = 0
if(currentChannel < len(combo) - 1):
    if(currentChannel != 0):
        remainingNodes -= combo[currentChannel - 1]
        for i in range(0, remainingNodes):
            combo[currentChannel] = i
            sum + 1
        generate(nodes - i, combo, currentChannel + 1, remainingNodes)
        print(sum)
# base case
if(currentChannel == len(combo) - 1):
    combo[currentChannel] = nodes
    channelSet = range(len(combo))
    for i in range(0, len(combo)):
        channelSet[i] = combo[i]
    availableCombos.append(channelSet)

# computes the total number of combos
# and displays sets of channels that were generated
def totalAssignments(combos, nodes):
totalCombos = 0
for combo in combos:
    totalCombos += countCombos(combo, nodes, 0)
    '{}{}{}'.format(countCombos(combo, nodes, 0),
                    " sets with occupancies: ", combo)
'{}{}'.format("Total number of assignments: ", totalCombos)

def countCombos(combo, nodes, currentChannel):
if(currentChannel < len(combo)):
    binomials = binomial(nodes, combo[currentChannel])
    recursed = countCombos(combo, int(nodes) -
                           int(combo[currentChannel]), currentChannel + 1)
    result = binomials * recursed
    return result
return 1

def binomial(n, k):
if(k == n or k == 0):
    return 1
result = binomial(n - 1, k - 1) + binomial(n - 1, k)
return result
def main():
start()


main()
```

Comment: indentation is absolutely wrong. I hope you are not using this code. also, you are supposed to give an account of error you are getting.

Comment: Will review my syntax, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this code:

- As @Pbd said: indentation is wrong, in Python that's a big deal.
- Assuming that indentation is wrong because of copy & paste, the other major problem is that `while True`, you really need an exit condition.
- Just removing the `while True` makes the code exit, but I don't know if that's what you want
- You only do the `format`, but you're not `print`ing the string or returning it.
- Even if you were returning the formatted string, you're just not using it.
- Do not try to name a variable [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), that's a bad idea in basically any language and especially Python

There's also a number of stylistic issues (use snake_case instead of camelCase, just rename `start` to `main`, check that the script is being called correctly and so on), but I'd say fix the other problems first.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I took a leap into Python syntax and failed gloriously it seems. The 'while True' was meant to be so that the program would always restart, but I have removed it, for now. It's kind of working as expected but not giving the right results I would say.

Comment: I think you're just being a bit hasty, probably because you're used to some IDE that points out some mistakes and you don't have it here. Big news: as a beginner it's better if you don't use an IDE. You need to understand the basics before you let something else take care of them :-) Feel free to post another question with the revised code, though.